# Retrieving GUI data from a backgroundworker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have a background worker which needs to grab `comboBox1.SelectedItem`, however it's on a different thread and thus I'm unable to "reach" the GUI (as the GUI is on the main thread).

How would I do this?

I've tried using a delegate however this doesn't seem to work.

```
private delegate string ReadComboDelegate(ComboBox c);

private string ReadComboBox(ComboBox c)
{
    if(c.InvokeRequired)
    {
        ReadComboDelegate del = new ReadComboDelegate(this.ReadComboBox);
        return (string) c.Invoke(del,c);
    }
    else
    {
        return c.Text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you should pass the SelectedItem (and any other data you might require) to the method representing the background worker.

If thats not possible, then you can use **comboBox1.Invoke** method to communicate with the UI thread.

Comment: Yes, I'm currently doing that using the `e.Argument` however I'm calling the backgroundworker from multiple methods, and chaning each of them isn't a real neat solution I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the combobox during a ReportProgress call.